# browser console is flooded with warning messages react hot-update

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

this is my Header.jsx component code .. can you point out where is the mistake ? i have searched whole internet for this but could not find any solution . and its not only about header component its happening for every component edited. if you edit the component first time it works fine and gives only one update info in console log.. but if you make another change it goes crazy and infinite and my browser crashes.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link, Router } from "react-router";
import Request from 'superagent';
import ErrorCodes from '../common/ErrorCodes.js';

require("../styles/less/style.less");
require("../styles/less/custom.less");
require("../styles/less/resize.less");

var HeaderComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <header className="main-header">
   {/*<!-- Logo -->*/}
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="logo">
    <img src={require("../img/logo2.png")} alt="" className="img-responsive" />
   </a>
  
   <nav className="navbar navbar-static-top">
    {/* Sidebar toggle button */}
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="sidebar-toggle" onClick={this.props.onClick} data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
     <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    </a>
   </nav>
  </header>;
    }
});

export default HeaderComponent;
```

this is my package.json

```json
{  
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "generic-pool": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-preprocess": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "install": "^0.8.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "nodemailer": "^2.6.4",
    "npm": "^3.10.8",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^6.1.0",
    "pg-parse-float": "0.0.1",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.3",
    "react-transform": "0.0.3",
    "sendgrid": "^4.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "superagent": "^2.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",

    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.16.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",    
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. HMR outputs to the console whenever you modify something and it re-renders that component (in your case, `header.jsx`).

Comment: but it should update only once. If i change something in any react component it starts printing this message infinite times and my browser crashes. maybe because hot reloading happening multiple times on single change. how do i resolve it ? please help @j

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong with your header component which makes react rerender it in an infinite loop?

Comment: i have added my header.jsx. if you can tell me where is the problem it will be great .. thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see what could have gotten wrong in that component. Could you jsfiddle a setup which replicates these console errors?

Comment: its behaving same for every component i update. not only for this component. which files you need to point out mistake... i am not able to set up jsfiddle .

Comment: I'm not sure how else to help you if it's unreproducible. If I were you though, I'd try checking if the bundle actually does change physically by running a file watcher on the build directory. If none of the files change, there's probably something wrong with your build setup.